# Delete file in list. Seeing new line

Tags: php

I'm having a problem to delete files listed in a file. One file name per line

There are not many more than 10 or so listed at any time. It would seem the \n is also being read into the unlink command and showing the error no such filename.

I have tried the recommended rtrim without much luck.

filename

```
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
file4.php
etc...
```

This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
if(file_exists($filename)) {
$handle = fopen("$filename", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // process the line and delete read file.
        unlink("$line");
    }
}
else
    {
        // error opening the file.
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // process the line and delete read file.
    $line = trim($line);
    if (strlen($line) && file_exists($line)) {
        unlink($line);
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors in logs but no files are deleted. I put an echo line right after the trim line above strlen and it shows exactly were the file is and file name. But not deleting a file. I also put a echo line after file_exists and nothing is printed as if it's not being seen.

Comment: I found it. My tag/copy/paste and fat finger deleted a letter.

Comment: Thanks so much. I would have never got this.